# Could not install package 'Facebook 6.8.0'

Tags: facebook, xamarin

I have installed Xamarin Starter version, and want the App to access posts of some users on Facebook. I tried to add package the Facebook SDK for .Net, but it throws the error : "Could not install package 'Facebook 6.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

I tried to change the target framework version, but that did not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Facebook Component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk) for Xamarin.  Xamarin also has a [Xamarin Social](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social) component that includes Facebook integration.  You cannot use any arbitrary Nuget package with Xamarin - it has to be one that targets a compatible framework.  Unfortunately the Nuget manager does not allow you to easily filter out incompatible packages.

Comment: Just tried Xamarin's component and get: Could not install package 'Xamarin.Facebook 3.22.0.0'.  Lame.

Comment: Xamarin.Social does not work in Xamarin PCL.Could not install package 'xamstore-xamarin.social 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarinios10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the package contents via Nuget and manually added it as a reference to my solution and it compiled and referenced correctly.  I tried the first example in an iPhone solution [from this tutorial](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/) and everything worked.  Hope that helps.